# Google Chrome wrong position on small screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Google Chrome I've a problem with the css:
http://g4.nl/index.php/tour-x (use the link in Chrome):
[image: Picture doesn't fit in box]

The picture doesn't adjust to the screen size as the text does the same.

Is there an css fix for Chrome to solve this problem?
I don't have this problem on other browsers.

The code for the text including the image:

```
<p><strong><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1"><span style="color: #31994d;">Introductie</span></span></strong><strong><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1"><br /></span></strong></p>
<table style="height: 399px; width: 1319px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top">
<p style="text-align: justify;">De G4 TOUR-X is een bijzondere 3-piece bal. Hij combineert een aantal eigenschappen die men normaliter niet in één bal vindt. De bal voelt zeer zacht aan en geeft zeer veel backspin. Daarnaast is het een echte distance bal. Zelfs met lage swingsnelheden wordt een hoge launch en daarmee grote afstand behaald. Wat deze bal echter vooral bijzonder maakt is zijn prijs. De TOUR-X bevindt zich namelijk qua performance op het niveau van premium ballen, maar met een prijs van € 1,98 per stuk op een prijsniveau dat zelfs voor een goede 2-piece bal laag genoemd mag worden.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a style="text-align: center;" title="Klik voor USGA Conforming Golf Ball list 2013 in PDF" href="images/PDF/gball_list-7-2013.pdf" target="_blank">Conforms with USGA Rules</a></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong style="line-height: 1.3em;">Adviesprijs:&nbsp;</strong><span style="line-height: 1.3em;">€ 23,75 per dozijn</span></p>
<p><span style="color: #31994d;"><strong style="line-height: 1.3em;">Doelgroep</strong></span></p>
<ul>
<li>Spelers op zoek naar een bal voor maximale afstand met de driver&nbsp;</li>
<li><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">Spelers die een bal zoeken met een drop &amp; stop effect</span></li>
<li><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">Spelers die een bal zoeken met op en rond de greens een zeer zacht gevoel</span></li>
<li><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">Spelers met een swingsnelheid met de driver van 80 tot 115 mph&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
<strong style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1"><strong style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<br /></span></strong></span></strong></td>
<td style="width: 450px;" valign="top">
<p><strong style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">&nbsp;</span></strong></p>
<p><strong style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1"><strong style="line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1"><img style="float: left;" src="images/Ballen/TOUR-X_3D_shadow.png" alt="TOUR-X 3D shadow" width="364" height="353" /><br style="clear: left;" /></span></strong></span></strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 250px;"><img src="images/Ballen/Core-1_green.png" alt="Core-1 green" width="275" height="157" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 800px;" align="left" valign="top">
<p><span style="color: #31994d;"><strong>POLYBUTADIENE CORE</strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">De binnenste kern van de TOUR-X bestaat uit high speed polybutadiene. Dit is het geheim achter de enorme afstand die met de bal behaald wordt bij slagen met de driver.&nbsp;De kern wordt gradueel massiever waardoor de spin afneemt naarmate de bal harder wordt geraakt. De spinrate bij de korte clubs blijft dus hoog, terwijl de spin bij de driver juist laag blijft voor extra afstand.</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 500px;" align="left" valign="top">
<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="images/Ballen/Core-2_grey.png" alt="Core-2 grey" width="283" height="162" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 500px;" align="left" valign="top">
<p><span style="color: #31994d;"><strong>ELASTOMEER CORE</strong></span></p>
<p>De tweede kern zorgt voor extra spin op de slagen met de ijzers terwijl de spin met de driver juist niet toeneemt.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 500px;" align="left" valign="top">
<p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="images/Ballen/Cover.png" alt="Cover" width="283" height="162" /></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td style="width: 500px;" align="left" valign="top">
<p><span style="color: #31994d;"><strong>VLMI SURLYN COVER 332 DIMPLES</strong></span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">De zeer zachte cover van deze bal is gemaakt van het nieuwe allerzachtste surlyn dat er bestaat. Dit materiaal is beduidend minder gevoelig voor beschadigingen bij het gebruik van ijzers dan het zeer kwetsbare urethane.</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">Een uniek procedé zorgt ervoor dat deze bal zijn zachtheid behoudt en extra spin genereert, zelfs bij korte pitches en chips. Het zachte impactgeluid geeft samen met de zeer zachte cover een comfortabel gevoel bij het putten en chippen.&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">De hexagonale circulaire dimplevorm zorgt voor een high launch effect. Zelfs bij lagere clubsnelheden met de driver zorgt dit voor een penetrerende balvlucht en een optimale landingshoek voor extra rol.&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a title="Klik voor USGA Conforming Golf Ball list 2013 in PDF" href="images/PDF/gball_list-7-2013.pdf" target="_blank">Conforms with USGA Rules</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong style="line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">&nbsp;</span></strong></p>
<p><strong style="line-height: 1.3em;"><span style="line-height: 1.3em;" data-mce-mark="1">&nbsp;</span></strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a width on the table of `1319px` that Google Chrome is not resizing. Try taking that width style completely off.